# 2000 Honda Accord Shakes under acceleration

Tags: honda, accord, manual-transmission, acceleration, shaking

I have have Honda Accord 2000 with manual 5 gear transmission. 
During acceleration it shakes like front end is ready to jump out. Engine doesn't misfire or anything - I have plenty of power on all RPMs and no hesitation - car just goes! However under acceleration it shakes horribly. Also I noticed that if I accelerate gently - lets say shift very early so that wheels don have much power provided to them, then car shakes less, but the moment I downshift and "put pedal to the metal" it shakes really badly.

Can someone tell me what is going on? What would be an easy way to test (so I can do it) and what what should be changed/fix from cheaper to more expensive stuff?

Thank you.

Comment: Where are you feeling the shaking? Is the whole vehicle vibrating? The wheel? The shifter? Do you notice the same thing if you accelerate in reverse (carefully!)? Is the behavior the same in every gear?

Comment: Shakes front end, it feels like it is coming from wheels. Shifter doesn't shake. Behavior is the same in every gear, as long as I can manage decent acceleration.

Comment: Note for answers - the Accord 2000 is a front-wheel drive car with an open differential.

Comment: I suspect the engine mounts. They are obviously stressed under acceleration. One way to check is to open the hood and look at the engine while someone else revs the engine. If there is noticeable lift, one or more engine mounts may be bad. If you have never had your engine mounts replaced, this is likely. I had a 2001 Accord with 3.0 liter V6 and had to have my engine mounts replaced at a bit over 100,000 miles. As I recall, the symptoms were the same as yours.

Comment: how about between 20-25 in second gear under acceleration? have this problem on a 01' honda accord 2.3 vtec. i replaced the axles and rotated the tires to check if those were the problems.

Comment: Being a 2000 mod year I'd have a look at my suspension and subframe mounts to see if the joints, bushings, and everything else is in good condition.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like its shaking at higher RPMs. Check plugs, distributor, and exhaust for leaks. Also check your motor mounts.

It may be your harmonic balancer. Check to see if its securely in place

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a wheel balance and alignment. If that doesn't help may have to check a mechanic . Spindles could even be bent.

Answer (score -1):

Does the accelerate happen consistently/all the time within a particular speed range e.g. 40-50 miles/hr? If so, you might have a bad axle.